# how can i drop a row with a known column value?

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I have a data frame where I found a -1 in the age column so how can I drop the entire row? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLOss.png)

Comment: `df[df['age'] != -1]` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do something like

```
df = df[df['age'] != -1]
```

if you want to drop all rows with negative values then

```
df = df[df['age'] < 0]
```